# Preview de imagenes en html muestra todas las imagenes al mismo tiempo | php

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Estoy realizando un Preview de imágenes, usando la ruta de las imágenes que guardo en una tabla MySQL.
Las imágenes se cargan bien y los indicadores arriba del Preview funciona como debería.
El problema es que al recargar la página el Preview por primera vez, me muestra todas las imágenes de los indicadores y no únicamente 1 por defecto.
Hasta el momento en el que presiono un indicador funciona como se supone que funcione.

Al cargar la página:

[image: slider1]

Al presionar un indicador:

[image: slider2]

Mi codigo:

```
                 <div class="leftSideAct">

                    <!-- Estos son los indicadores, cada indicador tiene un id> one,two... -->
                    <ul class="previewImg"> 
                        <?php
                        $sql = "SELECT t.id_departamento, t.nombre_terreno, td.id_terreno, td.direccion_terrenodetails, td.area_terrenodetails, td.categoria_terrenodetails, td.descripcion_terrenodetails, td.servicios_terrenodetails, td.img_path_terrenodetails1,td.img_path_terrenodetails2,td.img_path_terrenodetails3,td.img_path_terrenodetails4 FROM terrenos as t INNER JOIN terrenodetails as td ON t.id_terreno = td.id_terreno WHERE td.id_terreno=$terrenoValue";
                        if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
                        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                        ?>
                        <li class="dataToggle imgVisor" data-img="one"><img
                                src="<?php echo $row['img_path_terrenodetails1']?>" alt=""></li>
                        <li class="dataToggle imgVisor" data-img="two"><img
                                src="<?php echo $row['img_path_terrenodetails2']?>" alt=""></li>
                        <li class="dataToggle imgVisor" data-img="three"><img
                                src="<?php echo $row['img_path_terrenodetails3']?>" alt=""></li>
                        <li class="dataToggle imgVisor" data-img="four"><img
                                src="<?php echo $row['img_path_terrenodetails4']?>" alt=""></li>

                        <?php
                            }
                        mysqli_free_result($result);
                        } else{
                        echo "No se encontró ninguna imagen.";
                        }
                        } else{
                        echo "$sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
                        }
                        ?>

                    </ul>
                    <!-- Este es el preview, cada preview recibe el id del indicador> one,two... -->
                    <!-- Soy conciente que estoy cargando las 4 imagenes en este while, deberia usar el ID del indicador desde la base de datos para desplegar esta imagen? -->
                    <div class="contentImgVisor">

                        <?php
                        $sql = "SELECT t.id_departamento, t.nombre_terreno, td.id_terreno, td.direccion_terrenodetails, td.area_terrenodetails, td.categoria_terrenodetails, td.descripcion_terrenodetails, td.servicios_terrenodetails, td.img_path_terrenodetails1,td.img_path_terrenodetails2,td.img_path_terrenodetails3,td.img_path_terrenodetails4 FROM terrenos as t INNER JOIN terrenodetails as td ON t.id_terreno = td.id_terreno WHERE td.id_terreno=$terrenoValue";
                        if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
                        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                        ?>
                        <div id="one" class="imgContent dic"><img
                                src="<?php echo $row['img_path_terrenodetails1']?>" alt=""></div>
                        <div id="two" class="imgContent dic"><img
                                src="<?php echo $row['img_path_terrenodetails2']?>" alt=""></div>
                        <div id="three" class="imgContent dic"><img
                                src="<?php echo $row['img_path_terrenodetails3']?>" alt=""></div>
                        <div id="four" class="imgContent dic"><img
                                src="<?php echo $row['img_path_terrenodetails4']?>" alt=""></div>
                        <?php
                            }
                        mysqli_free_result($result);
                        } else{
                        echo "No se encontró ninguna imagen.";
                        }
                        } else{
                        echo "$sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
                        }
                        ?>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

tablas usadas en el proceso:

```
CREATE TABLE terrenos(
id_terreno int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
...
PRIMARY KEY(id_terreno),
INDEX(id_departamento), foreign key(id_departamento) references departamentos(id_departamento));

CREATE TABLE terrenodetails(
id_terrenodetails int not null AUTO_INCREMENT, 
id_terreno int not null,
...
img_path_terrenodetails1 varchar(200), 
img_path_terrenodetails2 varchar(200), 
img_path_terrenodetails3 varchar(200), 
img_path_terrenodetails4 varchar(200), 
PRIMARY KEY (id_terrenodetails), 
INDEX(id_terreno), foreign key(id_terreno) references terrenos(id_terreno));
```

Deberia agregarle un campo llamado ID a la tabla Terrenos y hacer otro while en el Preview en base a este ID?
Agradeceria cualquier idea o comentario,

Saludos,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedo evaluar que tan eficiente sea esto pero para mi proposito funciona perfectamente,

Lo he solucionado de la siguiente forma,

- guardo las imagenes en una variable $img1, $img2...
- En vista que al presionar los indicadores si me muestra el Preview entonces asumi que por default le agrega un display:block al indicador activo y un display:none a los demas.
- Por lo tanto cree una clase llamada *oculto* con la propiedad display:none y agregue esta propiedad a los Preview> two, three, four.

De esta forma al cargar la pagina queda activo el Preview> one, y los demas se ocultan hasta que los indicadores se activen.

```
             <div class="leftSideAct">

                        <!-- Estos son los indicadores, cada indicador tiene un id> one,two... -->
                        <ul class="previewImg"> 
                            <?php
                            $sql = "SELECT t.id_departamento, t.nombre_terreno, td.id_terreno, td.direccion_terrenodetails, td.area_terrenodetails, td.categoria_terrenodetails, td.descripcion_terrenodetails, td.servicios_terrenodetails, td.img_path_terrenodetails1,td.img_path_terrenodetails2,td.img_path_terrenodetails3,td.img_path_terrenodetails4 FROM terrenos as t INNER JOIN terrenodetails as td ON t.id_terreno = td.id_terreno WHERE td.id_terreno=$terrenoValue";
                            if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
                            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                                    $valorN=$row['id_terreno'];
                                    $img1=$row['img_path_terrenodetails1'];
                                    $img2=$row['img_path_terrenodetails2'];
                                    $img3=$row['img_path_terrenodetails3'];
                                    $img4=$row['img_path_terrenodetails4'];
                            ?>
                            <li class="dataToggle imgVisor" data-img="one"><img
                                    src="<?php echo $row['img_path_terrenodetails1']?>" alt=""></li>
                            <li class="dataToggle imgVisor" data-img="two"><img
                                    src="<?php echo $row['img_path_terrenodetails2']?>" alt=""></li>
                            <li class="dataToggle imgVisor" data-img="three"><img
                                    src="<?php echo $row['img_path_terrenodetails3']?>" alt=""></li>
                            <li class="dataToggle imgVisor" data-img="four"><img
                                    src="<?php echo $row['img_path_terrenodetails4']?>" alt=""></li>

                            <?php
                                }
                            mysqli_free_result($result);
                            } else{
                            echo "No se encontró imagen para este terreno.";
                            }
                            } else{
                            echo "$sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
                            }
                            ?>

                        </ul>
                        <!-- Este es el preview, cada preview recibe el id del indicador> one,two... -->
                        <div class="contentImgVisor">


                            <div id="one" class="imgContent dic"><img
                                    src="<?php echo $img1?>" alt=""></div>
                            <div id="two" class="imgContent dic oculto"><img
                                    src="<?php echo $img2?>" alt=""></div>
                            <div id="three" class="imgContent dic oculto"><img
                                    src="<?php echo $img3?>" alt=""></div>
                            <div id="four" class="imgContent dic oculto"><img
                                    src="<?php echo $img4?>" alt=""></div>


                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Saludos cordiales